# Отношения laravel, не удается получить id из таблицы posts

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Всем привет. Я новенький в laravel. Не удается получить id из таблицы posts. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка и как её исправить.

*1) Есть 3 таблицы - users, posts, comments.*

**Миграция users**:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Миграция posts:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('detail');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Миграция comments:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('author_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('text');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

*2) Есть 3 модели - User, Post, Comments.*

**Модель User:**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comments::class);
}
```

**Модель Post:**

```
 public function users()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
 }

 public function comments()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(Comments::class);
 }
```

**Модель Comments:**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

*3) Есть контроллер - **CommentsController**:*

```
public function index()
{
    $comments = Comments::latest()->paginate(8);

    return view('posts.comments', compact('comments'))->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}

public function create()
{
    return view('posts.createcomments');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'text' => 'required',
    ]);

    $comments = Comments::create();
    $comments->text = $request->get('text');
    $comments->author_id = $request->user()->id;
    $comments->post_id = $request->post()->id;
    $comments->save();

    return redirect()->route('comments.index')
        ->with('success', 'Post created successfully.');
}
```

При получении id из таблицы users - `$comments->author_id = $request->user()->id;`, все хорошо работает и id успешно получен, при написании `dd($request->user())` выдает: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот при получении id из таблицы posts - `$comments->post_id = $request->post()->id;`, ничего не работает, получаю ошибку: `ErrorException
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`, а написание `dd($request->post())`, выдает лишь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень грубо говоря: `Request $request` - это `$_REQUEST` с кучей плюшек от фреймворка, одна из которых `$request->user()` (доступ к текущему зарегистрированному пользователю). Вам нужно самостоятельно передавать из формы `id` модели Post или связывать через маршрут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ты в миграции не связываешь таблицы юзеров и постов. Добавь в миграцию для постов чтобы связать таблицы и посты.

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

И тогда можно доставать

Comment: Спасибо, добавил, все заработало.

Answer (score 2):

@Alexandr Revnuk: Насколько я понимаю, определить отношение можно и в модели, а вот id статьи необходимо передать явно.

Например, ***с помощью скрытого поля***:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}">
```

соответственно в контроллере валидировать и использовать:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'text' => 'required',
        'post_id' => 'required|integer',
    ]);

    $comments = Comments::create();
    $comments->text = $request->get('text');
    $comments->author_id = $request->user()->id;
    $comments->post_id = $request->get('post_id');
    $comments->save();

    return redirect()->route('comments.index')
        ->with('success', 'Post created successfully.');
}
```

но здесь необходимо будет проверить существование поста с переданным id.

***с помощью тега action формы***:

1 изменить action формы

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts/{{ $posts->id }}/comments">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Add a comment</label>
        <textarea id="text" name="text" cols="30" rows="4" 
            class="form-control" placeholder="Add a your comment" required
        >{{ old('text') }}</textarea>                       
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">отправить</button>
</form>
```

изменить роут (ВАЖНО: НЕ {id}, а именно {post}!!!)

```
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentsController@store');
```

и принять параметр Post $post в контроллере CommentsController:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  Post $post
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Post $post)
{
    request()->validate([
        'text' => 'required',
        'post_id' => 'required|integer',
    ]);

    $product = Product::create([
        'text' => request('text'),
        'post_id' => request('post_id'),
        'author_id' => auth()->user()->id,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('comments.index')
        ->with('success', 'Post created successfully.');
}
```

OFFTOP: разве в модели Posts отношение к Comments должно быть не hasMany?

```
// model Post
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comments::class);
}
```

Comment: `$table->foreign` тоже не помешает, для индексов.